Representation of graphs in group theory
Consider a simple directed graph $G$ with $n$ nodes. Is there any "nice" representation of $G$ as an element of an abelian group?
This question has a pretty clear answer - yes - as we can do various things such as using $\mathbb Z_2^{n^2-n}$, which just stores if an ordered pair of nodes have an edge between them. We can also use something like $\mathbb Z_{2^{n-1}}^n$ which stores a mask representing the set of nodes that a certain node $i$ is connected to.
However, these are forced and unnatural. The properties of the graph don't have much to do with the element of the group.
Is there any representation which preserves the properties of the graph? One example is again the famous graph isomorphism problem - is there a representation where an isomorphism between $G_1$ and $G_2$ directly corresponds to there existing a automorphism from the representation of $G_1$ and $G_2$ in the group and vice-versa. Furthermore, things like connectedness/cycles should be somewhat visible, but these are less important and the structure preservation matters way more (the isomorphism condition), so a representation missing this but keeping the first condition would also be very helpful.
Let me know about any thoughts/results in literature relating to these. Thanks.

The first one is not forced at all - it leads to the notion of the cycle space of the graph, from which you can define a reasonably "organic" planarity criterion.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_Lane%27s_planarity_criterion

This is cool. Thanks!

This is not necessarily a full answer, or the answer you’re looking for, but in my opinion the most natural way to consider the graph itself as an element of an Abelian group is to consider the edge space of $G$. The edge space is defined simply as the power set of the set of directed edges. The graph $G$ is the top element and the power set is an Abelian group under symmetric difference.
It’s not only an Abelian group, but a Boolean ring if we take addition to be symmetric difference and multiplication to be intersection. It’s also a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Combining both structures, the edge space is an algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$.
By considering the vertex space as well, the power set of the set of vertices, the incidence matrix of $G$ is a linear transformation between the edge space and vertex space. If $G$ is directed, then we should work with $\mathbb{F}_3$ or $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ rather than $\mathbb{F}_2$ in the incidence matrix. This allows us to use homological methods to explore the properties of the graph. The zeroth homology group measures connectedness and the first homology group measures the cycle structure.
The edge space also allows us to define two more important Abelian groups (vector spaces) from $G$, the cycle space and cut space. These are linear subspaces of the edge space and are orthogonal complements. This gives us a good entry into matroid theory.
Edit:
I see what you’re asking for now. If we generalize to all simple and looped digraphs, we can work with the set of all binary matrices $\Gamma = 2^{n^2}$ (which is an Abelian group under symmetric difference). We can define an equivalence relation over $\Gamma$ in which $A \sim B$ iff $A$ and $B$ are permutation similar, for $A, B \in \Gamma$. Each equivalence class is an isomorphism class of $n$-vertex digraphs.
Given a group $G$, there is an equivalence relation on its elements given by the orbits of the elements under the action of $Aut(G)$. You want to find the $G$ such that there is an injection $f: \Gamma \rightarrow G$ which induces an injection on equivalence classes $\tilde{f}: \Gamma/\sim \rightarrow G/\sim$.
This shouldn’t actually be terribly difficult since the only structure $f$ has to respect is equivalence classes. I can’t readily think of an explicit non-trivial example off the top of my head, I’ll need a sec, but I believe many such $G$ should exist for all $n$.

@mathfan2023 I think you’ve asked an interesting question, I’m just a little confused on what exactly you’d like to see. Are you looking for a representation of the graph or its automorphism group? When you say the graph is an element of an Abelian group, what do you feel the other elements of the group should be? Automorphism groups aren’t generally Abelian, and representations don’t generally have a group structure

@mathfan2023 Do you know any category theory? Are you asking for a particular functor from the category of digraphs to some monoidal category or maybe a group object in the category of digraphs? Do you want to define some kind of monad on the category of digraphs?

@Naaim Ah sorry about being confusing, let me rephrase my question. Say we have a fixed $n$ and we are considering graphs on $n$ nodes. Let $S$ be the set of these graphs. My goal is to find a group $G$ such that there exists a function $f: S\to G$ such that graphs $G_1, G_2$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists an automorphism in $G$ mapping $f(G_1)$ to $f(G_2)$.

@mathfan2023 No worries at all and I think I understand now, let me know if this is what you were looking for!

@Naaim I feel like this is actually really hard (would be surprised if there's a really easy way to do this). Particularly, automorphisms in a cyclic group can do a lot of wonky things. Trying to store stuff like a mask of all adjacent nodes or something along those lines could get bad if you take the automorphism k -> n-k in the cyclic group of order n (and do this for each component or something)

@mathfan2023 Sorry I should have wrote my response better, I meant an existence proof that such groups should exist for all $n$. Finding explicit constructions for large $n$ is difficult since just finding an easy/efficient way to construct the equivalence relation on $\Gamma$ requires an efficient solution to the graph isomorphism problem. Also, since group automorphisms aren’t generally all inner, explicitly listing them presents its own challenge
